# Can ViewVC send automated reports?

Tags: cvs, viewvc

Current we use viewvc to browse our CVS repository and it works quite well, but lately we've started to get requests for some automated reporting functionality and I can't seem to find a way to do that with the standard tools and I figured I'd ask here before writing something myself.

Comment: I set it up for my previous company and even though that was a number of years ago, I don't recall it having any such features. The github repo still seems to active so it might be worth having a look there.

Comment: No, I don't believe so. However, ViewVC does organize your commits in a nice database function so rolling your own automated reports would be much easier done through the ViewVC database rather than mining CVS directly.

Comment: I hadn't realized that about the database.  Thank you both

Answer (score 0):

ViewVC doesn't offer anything by way of *automated* reporting.  It is, in a sense, just a glorified user interface for the sorts of information readily available from the version control system's (CVS or Subversion) standard tool chain.  That said, as Logan indicated, ViewVC does offer a database (MySQL) integration that provides a somewhat easier and quicker way to query the commits made in the repository with particular filtering (by author, within a date range, etc.)

See the `[cvsdb]` portion of the `viewvc.conf` configuration file for configuration of this feature.

You'll also want to be aware of a few of the scripts that ViewVC ships in its `bin/` subdirectory:

- `make-database` creates in your MySQL instance the tables necessary for this database integration to work at all.
- `cvsdbadmin rebuild /path/to/repository` will crawl the repository and populate the database.
- `loginfo-handler` can be used in your CVS repository's post-commit hook to keep the database up to date with any new commits that land.